# Como usar uma variável que representa o nome de uma Label para mudar o valor dela?

Tags: vb.net, variáveis, reflexão

Criei um método para formar um <kbd>Name</kbd> que existe de alguma `Label` do programa, e dar um valor numérico á propriedade `Text` dessa `Label` formada.

E preciso só conseguir fazer tipo isso:

```
Variavel = "NameDaLabel"
Variavel.Text = "Valor"
```

Tenho as seguintes variaveis:

```
Dim VarRetrocede As Integer  = 9
Dim VarNomeInicial As String = "Index_"
```

Tenho um código em um `Timer` que retrocede o valor de 9 segundos da variável `VarRetrocede`, e quero que regresse até **1**:

```
VarRetrocede = VarRetrocede - 1
```

E até esse valor chegar á 1 tem um código rodando ao mesmo tempo, que combina a `VarNomeInicial` e `VarRetrocede` para formar um `Name` de alguma `Label`, porque todos os `Name` das `Label` estão nesse padrão: "Index_2" e algum numero, 
e o valor das `Text` das `Label` são iguais ao número. E enquanto o código forma um `Name`, um valor numérico é dado a `Label` que foi combinada no momento:

```
VarNomeIncial.Text = VarRetrocede
```

Então o `Text` dela vai ser o valor da `VarRetrocede`, do momento em que ela foi combinada.

Mas como é uma variável não da pra mudar o Text.

Preciso muito disso, é possivel? Ficarei muito agradecido por qualquer resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente pegar o controle pelo nome dele:

```
Dim referencia As Label = DirectCast(Me.Controls("Index_3"), Label)
referencia.Text = 3
```

Se não der certo, use o Control.Find

```
Dim referencia As Label = Me.Controls.Find("Index_3", False)
referencia.Text = 3
```